# Laptop Battery Diagnostics Software?

Tags: windows-7, battery, compaq-laptop

My Compaq CQ50-215CA laptop with Windows 7 Ultimate RC 32-bit recently told me to replace my battery for fear of sudden shutdowns. Is there any good diagnostics software that anyone has used to test for battery condition and max. life? Also what are good practices for keeping maximal battery life?

Thanks.

Comment: you can use batteryinfoview (freeware) http://www.windowstechinfo.com/2015/06/how-to-know-lap-battery-replacement-time-before-battery-dies-batteryinfoview.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [BatteryCare](http://batterycare.bkspot.com/en/index.html) is a good tool.
- [BatteryUniversity](http://www.batteryuniversity.com/) is a good source for information.

Comment: Thanks! I'm surprised how much my battery has worn after a year already. :P

Comment: very good. it shows hdd and cpu temperatures, and warns about "real" time to discharge when battery, for example, discharges with 70% of load.

Comment: Some people say, that BatteryUniversity is not 100% reliable source of information.

Answer (score 3):

You may be able to use [HP's Battery Check](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&docname=c00625471#N874):

> Not all models of this notebook series
>   are supported. To determine if you
>   model is support, download the HP
>   Battery Check from the following
>   address and install the Battery Check
>   ( [HP Battery Check (SP41862) File
>   Download](ftp://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp41501-42000/sp41862.exe) ). A message will be
>   displayed if your system is not
>   supported.

If not, check out [Imtec Battery Mark](http://en.imtec.org.ru/load/7-1-0-5):

> - Produces test in two modes (fast and normal) with two variants of play
>     on hardware load subsystem notebook:
>     full load, or without it.
> - At the time of testing construct a detailed schedule of changes in the
>     level of battery power. After testing
>     all the data stored in a log file for
>     later viewing and / or analysis.
> - The program fully supports multi-and multicore processors, which
>     allows to reproduce the maximum
>     possible load on the processor system
>     to test a laptop in extreme
>     conditions.
> - After the testing, the total assessment system power notebooks,
>     calculated by a unique algorithm,
>     taking into account not only the time
>     of the battery, and laptop performance
>     during testing.

or [BatteryMon](http://www.passmark.com/products/batmon.htm):

> - Graphically see the charge /    discharge rate
> - Diagnose problem    battery cells with detailed    statistics
> - Compare and measure your    batteries' performance with expected
>     discharge rates
> - See the critical    discharge point for your batteries
> - Uniquely identify battery packs for    tracking purposes or system
>     inventories
> - Log the performance of a    battery for later reference
> - See the    status of each individual battery    pack, when
>     multiple batteries are in    use

Comment: batterymon is shareware

Answer (score 1):

I love [BattStat](http://users.rcn.com/tmtalpey/BattStat/), free and powerful

Comment: powerful, but does not show numeric info in tray...