# battery meter for laptops

Tags: laptop, battery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Laptop Battery Diagnostics Software?](https://superuser.com/questions/99548/laptop-battery-diagnostics-software)

For laptops, which battery monitor software do you suggest?

Thank you.